# "Command 'npm' not found" after open terminal, but npm -v show it is installed (installation used nvm)

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I installed npm and node using nvm, and it work's fine, but after computer rebot it shows some errors.

Right after rebot open dialog (in Polish language) saying:

> error loading the file /home/pawel/.profile
> /home/pawel/.bashrc: line 5: npm: command not found

[image: right after open terminal]
[image: this shows just after computer rebot]
[image]
[image: home folder]
[image: .npm folder]
[image: home/pawel/.profile]

Comment: Did you try the full path to the npm executable in your script?

Comment: thanks, but sounds like bad idea

Comment: Why? The full path the the npm command is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `nvm` which allows you to have multiple versions of Node.js and to automatically select one of them. This works by placing a script at the end of your `.bashrc` that allows the correct Node.js to be picked up. So if you try to access `npm` in the beginning of that same script, it won't work because that path has not been set up.